# Hardware / Software Preconditions to run/install a 64-Bit guest

Tags: 64-bit, virtualization, windows-server-2008, hypervisor

I just need to install Windows 2008 64-Bit on a virtual machine. How to? Do I need a special type of processor? Do I need a "special" hypervisor? Actually installation fails on startup with the following hint:

> Installation stopped with following information: File:
>   `\windows\system32\boot\winload.exe`
>   `Status: 0xc000035a Info:` Attempting to
>   load a 64-bit application, however
>   this CPU is not compatible with 64-bit
>   mode

My host system: Windows 7 64Bit 
My CPU: Pentium D (seems to be Smithfield 805 - no Intel virtualization technology).

I tried following hypervisors: Microsoft VPC 2007, VirtualBox, VMWare - all without success!

Comment: Vmware what? They make at least a dozen products.

Answer (score 0):

You need VT to run a 64 bit guest on every platform that I'm aware of. You'll most likely need a new CPU